# Special Characters and a simple select query

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, special-characters

I have got a problem with a simple Select Query and special chars. I want to select the name Änne.

```
SELECT *  FROM `names` WHERE `name` = 'Änne'
```

**utf8_general_ci**

- Änne
- Anne

okay, ...

> utf8 general ci is a very simple collation. What it does it just 
>   removes all accents then converts to upper case and uses the code of this sort of "base letter" result letter to compare. 
>   http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748

**utf8_unicode_ci**

- Änne
- Anne

why?

**utf8_bin**

- Änne

utf8_bin seems to be the right choice at this point, but i have to do my search case insensitiv.

```
SELECT *  FROM `names` WHERE `name` = 'änne'
```

**utf8_bin**

- none

Is there no way to do so?

I could use php ucwords() to uppercase the first letters, but i would prefer to find a DB solution.
edit: ucwords('änne') = änne, so i cant use that too

---

```
SELECT *  FROM `names` WHERE lower(`name`) = 'änne'
```

is working for me, because i don't have a difference between 'Änne' and 'änne' in my DB.

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
SELECT * FROM `names` WHERE upper(`name`) = upper("änne")
```

[Quoting doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html):

> The default character set and collation are latin1 and
>   latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case
>   insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name
>   LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a. To make
>   this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a
>   case sensitive or binary collation

That means that case sensitive results are because you have set a binary collation. You can set collation column to utf8_general_ci and change it on searchs:

```
col_name COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE 'a%'
```

Comment: I can not use upper since it returns the string with all characters changed to uppercase. in my case it is just the first letter.

`SELECT *  FROM names WHERE name COLLATE latin1_general_cs = 'änne'` results in:

#1253 - COLLATION 'latin1_general_cs' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'

Comment: Reading doc it seems that case insensitive is dependant to compare special characters with 'base' letter and viceversa.

Comment: Seems to be true for utf8_general_ci http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your MySQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = "Änne"
```

Remove the quotes around the table name and the field name.

Comment: sorry, got a strange error message at my first post attempt, so i removed the backticks. now it should be okay.